# How to use jquery.slimscroll in spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, module

I want to use slimscroll for a couple of SPFX webparts but having trouble to get things going.

I used:

```
npm i jquery-slimscroll
npm i @types/jquery.slimscroll
```

next to a couple of other modules (jquery etc).

To get things working in the workbench I have to use

```
import "jquery.slimscroll";
```

In the config.json I defined:

```
"jquery.slimscroll": {
  "path": "https://...../jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
  "globalName": "jQuery"
}
```

as an external.

So in the workbench this is actually working.

But when bundling  `gulp bundle --ship`, `gulp package-solution --ship` and moving stuff to SP2016 it does not work. IE11 sometimes shows the WP ok (mostly at first load), Chrome almost never displays things ok.

In the console I have this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d(...).slimScroll is not a function
```

I tried all sorts of things like different import statements. using require in stead off import. But all seem to let the transpiler generate: `error TS2339: Property 'slimScroll' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.`

Anybody a clue how to properly use jquery.slimscroll in SPFX / typescript?